# React Native Beginner Image Tag

Tags: react-native, image

Hello everyone.
I'm trying to follow a course on ReactNative, and I encountered an issue that I don't understand. I'm using expo, to start the project, and on my home page everything is fine:

```js
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import { SparklesIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/solid';
// import { SparklesIcon as SparklesIconOutline } from 'react-native-heroicons/outline';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Categories from '../components/Categories';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">
      {/* Header */}
      <View className="flex-row p-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2">
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
          }}
          className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-500 p-4 rounded-full"
        />
        <View className="flex-1">
          <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now!</Text>
          <Text className="font-bold text-xl">
            Current Location
            <Icon name="expand-more" color="#00CCBB" />
          </Text>
        </View>

        <Icon name="person-outline" color="#00CCBB" size="35px" />
      </View>
  {/* ... */}
```

But for the components view, it's impossible to display images, and I really don't understand why:

```js
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import CategoryCard from './CategoryCard';

const Categories = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingTop: 10,
      }}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
      {/* CategoryCard */}
      <CategoryCard imgUrl="https://links.papareact.com/wru" title="Testing1" />
            {/* ... */}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const CategoryCard = ({ imgUrl, title }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
        }}
        className="h-20 w-20 rounded"
      />
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default CategoryCard;
```

It's sure I missed something, but I don't know what.
[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try setting a height and a width for the image: `<Image style={{height: 200, width: 200}} ...`

Comment: Ok thank you very much, sorry for that it was effectively this, but like I used Tailwind, to me it was ok with ```className="h-20 w-20 rounded"``` but I have to search why Tailwind doesn't work on this component  again

Answer (score 1):

Provide `height`, `width` and `resizeMode` to the Image style